# Is this sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity

> I was issued the lunch card for the canteen.

I heard this in a listening test, but I think it is wrong: "issue" cannot be used in the same manner as such verbs as "give" and "teach," as in "give A B," and "teach A B."

So, "...was issued with the..." is correct, in my sight.

Am I wrong on this?

Answer (score 1):

When I first read

**I was issued the lunch card for the canteen.**

I thought it was grammatical. It wasn't till checking various dictionary definitions and thinking about how to form a sentence in the passive, and making comparisons with verbs similar to issue that *I gave up that line of inquiry and decided to just Google the phrase 'I was issued'.*

I found out that cities from [New York](http://www.villageofbronxville.com/parking/faq/i-think-i-was-issued-a-parking-ticket-in-error-what-should-i-do?device=desktop) to [California](http://alamedaca.gov/police/faq/1141) use the phrase. So I am going with my initial feeling, although others may wish to do nGrams or make other arguments, I am gonna say it is grammatical based on widespread use. (Note: the usage is not limited to tickets, by the way.)

Comment: *Issue* participates in the Dative Alternation, just like *give*: ① *X **issued** [the lunch card] to me. → [The lunch card] **was issued** to me (by X).* ② *X **issued** [me] [the lunch card]. → [I] **was issued** [the lunch card] (by X).*

Comment: @snailboat What about "I was issued with"? Because that doesn't sound overly bad and does have some usage. Note: I wouldn't say it, but I think some people might say it, if only because "was issued" raises some question in their mind...

Comment: Oh, that's separate from the dative alternation―you'll notice *\*"[I] **was given with** X"* is ungrammatical. So we need to consider this combination a type of idiom, a "phrasal verb". Specifically, it's a verb + preposition phrase idiom (so it's not like *"**light up** [the room]"* where up can move to the end of the sentence, giving *"**light** [the room] **up**"*). It has both active and passive versions, too: ③ *X **issued** [me] **with** a lunch card.* → *[I] **was issued with** a lunch card (by X)*.